# Get new column with groupby and return the maximum to entire group

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a new column with the maximum next_crossing_down for the entire x street.
I have this:

```
cars = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                     'y': [7,None,13,14,22,None,9,13,14,15,16],
                     'next_crossing_down': [5,None,10,10,20,None,5,10,10,10,15]})

    x    y          next_crossing_down
0   1   7.0                 5.0
1   1   NaN                 NaN
2   1  13.0                10.0
3   1  14.0                10.0
4   1  22.0                20.0
5   1   NaN                 NaN
6   1   9.0                 5.0
7   2  13.0                10.0
8   2  14.0                10.0
9   2  15.0                10.0
10  2  16.0                15.0
```

And I would like this:

```
    x     y         next_crossing_down     next_crossing_down_max
0   1   7.0                 5.0                    20.0
1   1   NaN                 NaN                     NaN
2   1  13.0                10.0                    20.0
3   1  14.0                10.0                    20.0
4   1  22.0                20.0                    20.0
5   1   NaN                 NaN                     NaN
6   1   9.0                 5.0                    15.0
7   2  13.0                10.0                    15.0
8   2  14.0                10.0                    15.0
9   2  15.0                10.0                    15.0
10  2  16.0                15.0                    15.0
```

This is the closest that I have come. I get the right numbers, only not in the entire x_street.

```
cars['next_crossing_down_max']= cars.groupby(['x'])['next_crossing_down'].max()

    x    y         next_crossing_down     next_crossing_down_max
0   1   7.0                 5.0                     NaN
1   1   NaN                 NaN                    20.0
2   1  13.0                10.0                    15.0
3   1  14.0                10.0                     NaN
4   1  22.0                20.0                     NaN
5   1   NaN                 NaN                     NaN
6   1   9.0                 5.0                     NaN
7   2  13.0                10.0                     NaN
8   2  14.0                10.0                     NaN
9   2  15.0                10.0                     NaN
10  2  16.0                15.0                     NaN
```

Comment: Can you explain your output? Why does index 6 has the value 15 when it has the same id for which the max is 20

Comment: I am assuming that is a typo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `pandas.DataFrame.transform`?

```
import numpy as np
cars['next_crossing_down_max']= cars.groupby(['x'])['next_crossing_down'].transform('max')
cars['next_crossing_down_max'] = np.where(cars['next_crossing_down'].isnull(),
                                          np.nan,
                                          cars['next_crossing_down_max'])
```

Output

```
cars
Out[18]: 
    x     y  next_crossing_down  next_crossing_down_max
0   1   7.0                 5.0                    20.0
1   1   NaN                 NaN                     NaN
2   1  13.0                10.0                    20.0
3   1  14.0                10.0                    20.0
4   1  22.0                20.0                    20.0
5   1   NaN                 NaN                     NaN
6   1   9.0                 5.0                    20.0
7   2  13.0                10.0                    15.0
8   2  14.0                10.0                    15.0
9   2  15.0                10.0                    15.0
10  2  16.0                15.0                    15.0
```

Alternatively you could `mask` instead of `np.where`, which will get you the same result, but it's a bit slower (thanks to @Anky):

```
>>> cars.groupby("x")['next_crossing_down'].transform('max').mask(cars['next_crossing_down'].isna())

Out[19]: 
0     20.0
1      NaN
2     20.0
3     20.0
4     20.0
5      NaN
6     20.0
7     15.0
8     15.0
9     15.0
10    15.0
```

Comment: Thank you, this works just like I wanted. I have used cars.loc[cars['next_crossing_down'].isnull(), 'next_crossing_down_max'] = None to get rid of the unwanted values. Are they equal, or is one faster or more reliable than the other?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Thanks for accepting the answer. I would say that ```np.where``` is faster than the other, but both are reliable methods.